# Lockcat disabled

Tags: java, android

Lockcat has disabled and I can't see my application logs. Returns only the label "PROCESS STARTED (28828) for package com.example.myapplication"
How to restore logcat?

I can not find the right button to return everything back, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

View >> Tool Windows >> Logcat
[image]